# Prevent inserting data to database if data is exist

Tags: php, mysql, database

How to prevent inserting data to database if data is exist in database

ex : I have data

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $text = "Orange";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruit (text) VALUES ('$text')");
}
```

I want the text "orange" is inserted once to the "fruit" table 
and if there is text "Orange" again its not inserted to the "fruit" table
because the data is exist and have been inserted before

Comment: Why don't you add `unique constraint on a column` on db side ?

Comment: Please, for your own good, don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` extension. Instead, switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: If your loops grow bigger, you will encounter severe performance issues if you send the inserts one at a time. Take a look at the following syntax: `INSERT INTO tab(foo) VALUES ('bar'), ('baz'), ('meep')`. This way, three rows are created with one statement. Of course, the amount is flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$text = "Orange";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM fruit WHERE text = '$text');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruit (text) VALUES ('$text')");
    }else{
       echo "Duplicate";
       break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the column as Unique key...
This will prevent the duplicates

References:
[Primary Key and Unique Key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use INSERT IGNORE with unique key on text.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO fruit (text) VALUES ('$text')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use:

```
REPLACE INTO fruit (text) VALUES ('$text')
```

will insert new ones and for old ones, delete and insert again :)

But adding unique index on text field is the best way :D

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways:

- You would have to perform a select First and compare the results and then do the insert if no records found
- Add Unique to your datbase fields and insers won't be performed if there is a data
- Construct your query to check before insert
- Use Insert Ignore

Answer (score 0):

Most things in SQL are just like MySQL Unique Indexes, we learn just once.
Solving your example, we shall run something near

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stackoverflow2`.`fruit` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `text` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `text_UNIQUE` (`text` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

From MySQL doc,

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE
>   index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.
>   [[...]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)